# Creating directories and files recursively with bash expansion

Tags: bash

So I just have learned about bash expansion...and it's cool :) now I want to create some good plans for next year (just as an example).

I can't figure out how you can create folders and create some files within each folder in one pass... Is this possible or I need to get into each directory and repeat everything manually?

```
sean@COMMODORE:~$ mkdir plans && cd plans && mkdir 2021-CW{01..52}
sean@COMMODORE:~/plans$ ls
2021-CW01  2021-CW05  2021-CW09  2021-CW13  2021-CW17  2021-CW21  2021-CW25  2021-CW29  2021-CW33  2021-CW37  2021-CW41  2021-CW45  2021-CW49
2021-CW02  2021-CW06  2021-CW10  2021-CW14  2021-CW18  2021-CW22  2021-CW26  2021-CW30  2021-CW34  2021-CW38  2021-CW42  2021-CW46  2021-CW50
2021-CW03  2021-CW07  2021-CW11  2021-CW15  2021-CW19  2021-CW23  2021-CW27  2021-CW31  2021-CW35  2021-CW39  2021-CW43  2021-CW47  2021-CW51
2021-CW04  2021-CW08  2021-CW12  2021-CW16  2021-CW20  2021-CW24  2021-CW28  2021-CW32  2021-CW36  2021-CW40  2021-CW44  2021-CW48  2021-CW52
sean@COMMODORE:~/plans$ cd 2021-CW01
sean@COMMODORE:~/plans/2021-CW01$ touch {work,sport,shopping,music}.txt
sean@COMMODORE:~/plans/2021-CW01$ ls
music.txt  shopping.txt  sport.txt  work.txt
sean@COMMODORE:~/plans/2021-CW01$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify the first `mkdir` to just one command using `-p` to create the parent directory too:

```
mkdir -p plans/2021-CW{01..52}
```

and then use just a single `touch` to create the files in all directories

```
touch plans/2021-CW{01..52}/{work,sport,shopping,music}.txt
```

```
$ ls plans/2021-CW*
plans/2021-CW01:
music.txt  shopping.txt  sport.txt  work.txt

plans/2021-CW02:
music.txt  shopping.txt  sport.txt  work.txt

...

plans/2021-CW52:
music.txt  shopping.txt  sport.txt  work.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a script which you can use to do this :

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p plans/2021-CW{01..52} && cd plans

for d in */
do
    if [ -d "${d}" ] ; then 
        cd ${d} ; touch {work,sport,shopping,music}.txt ; cd ..
    fi
done
```